# Difference between std::result_of and decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, result-of

I have some trouble understanding the need for `std::result_of` in C++0x. If I understood correctly, `result_of` is used to obtain the resulting type of invoking a function object with certain types of parameters. For example:

```
template <typename F, typename Arg>
typename std::result_of<F(Arg)>::type
invoke(F f, Arg a)
{
    return f(a);
}
```

I don't really see the difference with the following code:

```
template <typename F, typename Arg>
auto invoke(F f, Arg a) -> decltype(f(a)) //uses the f parameter
{
    return f(a);
}
```

or

```
template <typename F, typename Arg>
auto invoke(F f, Arg a) -> decltype(F()(a)); //"constructs" an F
{
    return f(a);
}
```

The only problem I can see with these two solutions is that we need to either:

- have an instance of the functor to use it in the expression passed to decltype.
- know a defined constructor for the functor.

Am I right in thinking that the only difference between `decltype` and `result_of` is that the first one needs an expression whereas the second does not?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`result_of` was [introduced in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/utility/result_of.hpp), and then [included in TR1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1454.html), and finally in C++0x. Therefore `result_of` has an advantage that is backward-compatible (with a suitable library).

`decltype` is an entirely new thing in C++0x, does not restrict only to return type of a function, and is a language feature.

---

Anyway, on gcc 4.5, `result_of` is implemented in terms of `decltype`:

```
  template<typename _Signature>
    class result_of;

  template<typename _Functor, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes...)>
    {
      typedef
        decltype( std::declval<_Functor>()(std::declval<_ArgTypes>()...) )
        type;
    };
```

Comment: Ok, so it is mainly a convenience class to avoid the ugly expression in decltype, right?

Comment: As far as I understand `decltype` is uglier but also more powerful. `result_of` can only be used for types that are callable and it requires types as arguments. For example, you cannot use `result_of` here: `template <typename T, typename U> auto sum( T t, U u ) -> decltype( t + u );` if the arguments can be arithmetic types (there is no function `F` such that you can define `F(T,U)` to represent `t+u`. For user defined types you could. In the same way (I have not really played with it) I imagine that calls to member methods might be hard to do with `result_of` without using binders or lambdas

Comment: One note, decltype needs arguments to call the function with AFAIK, so without result_of<> it's awkward to get the type returned by a template without relying on the arguments having valid default constructors.

Comment: @RobertMason: Those arguments can be retrieved using `std::declval`, like the code I've shown above. Of course, this is ugly :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Your comment has unclosed parentheses that open with "(there is" :(

Comment: result_of won't work with functions that take by non-const reference AFAIK

Comment: Another note: `result_of` and its helper type `result_of_t` are deprecated as of C++17 in favour of `invoke_result` and `invoke_result_t`, alleviating some restrictions of the former. These are listed at the bottom of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of.

Answer (score 12):

If you need the type of something that isn't something like a function call, `std::result_of` just doesn't apply. `decltype()` can give you the type of any expression.

If we restrict ourselves to just the different ways of determining the return type of a function call (between `std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>` and `decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...)`), then there is a difference.

`std::result_of<F(Args...)` is defined as:

> If the expression
>   `INVOKE (declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...)` is well
>   formed when treated as an
>   unevaluated operand (Clause 5), the
>   member typedef type shall name the
>   type `decltype(INVOKE (declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...));`
>   otherwise, there shall be no member
>   type.

The difference between `result_of<F(Args..)>::type` and `decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...)` is all about that `INVOKE`. Using `declval`/`decltype` directly, in addition to being quite a bit longer to type, is only valid if `F` is directly callable (a function object type or a function or a function pointer). `result_of` additionally supports pointers to members functions and pointers to member data.

Initially, using `declval`/`decltype` guaranteed a SFINAE-friendly expression, whereas `std::result_of` could give you a hard error instead of a deduction failure. That has been corrected in C++14: `std::result_of` is now required to be SFINAE-friendly (thanks to [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3462.html)).

So on a conforming C++14 compiler, `std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>` is strictly superior. It's clearer, shorter, and correctly<sup>†</sup> supports more `F`s<sup>‡</sup> .

---

<sup>†</sup>Unless, that is, you're using it in a context where you don't want to allow pointers to members, so `std::result_of_t` would succeed in a case where you might want it to fail.

<sup>‡</sup> With exceptions. While it supports pointers to members, `result_of` will not work if you try to instantiate an invalid *type-id*. These would include a function returning a function or taking abstract types by value. Ex.:

```
template <class F, class R = result_of_t<F()>>
R call(F& f) { return f(); }

int answer() { return 42; }

call(answer); // nope
```

The correct usage would've been `result_of_t<F&()>`, but that's a detail you don't have to remember with `decltype`.

Comment: For a non-reference type `T` and a function `template<class F> result_of_t<F&&(T&&)> call(F&& f, T&& arg) { return std::forward<F>(f)(std::move(arg)); }`, is the usage of `result_of_t` correct?

Comment: Also, if the argument we pass to `f` is a `const T`, should we use `result_of_t<F&&(const T&)>`?