# A question about for_each in vector of c++

Tags: c++, stl, vector, struct, foreach

I have a question about the for_each in vector, the code is following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


struct myclass {
  void operator() (int i) {cout << " " << i;}
} myobject;

int main () {
  vector<int> myvector(3,4);

  cout << "\nmyvector contains:";
  for_each (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myobject);

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

should the third argument of for_each() be a function name?
if we pass the name of the struct, how does this works?

Comment: Related question: [Why override operator()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/317450/20984)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [*functor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B).

`std::for_each` is a function template that basically expands to this:

```
for (iter = myvector.begin(); iter != myvector.end(); ++iter)
{
    myobject(*iter);
}
```

So `myobject` can either be a function pointer, or it can be an object with an overload for `operator()`.

Comment: 'nuff said (SO doesn't think so) -- in fact the new standard affectionately refers to these creatures as [callable types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100015/c-metafunction-to-determine-whether-a-type-is-callable)

Comment: so this means we have to override the operator in struct?

Comment: @ratzip: Indeed, any struct that defines any `operator()` can be used as a functor.

Comment: @ratzip - not override, just define and implement. override would imply that there is a `virtual` base `operator()`.

Answer (score 2):

The third argument of `for_each` can be anything that *behaves like a function*, i.e. that can be invoked like `x()`. Since your struct overloads `operator()`, it has precisely this behaviour.

Classes which overload the ()-operator are called "functors" or "function objects". Their power lies in the fact that you can store additional data (e.g. accumulators or inital values) in the class members while still behaving like an ordinary function.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. `for_each` expects an object that can be called like a function (a *functor*). In other words, an object that overloads `operator()(T)` where T is the type of the values held in the container on which `for_each` is applied.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a function name, it's a function object (functor).

You can either do this manually yourself by defining a class with suitable `operator()` implementation, or wrap a function as a functor using [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/function.html) or similar.

Note that there is a subtle issue here.  If you define your `operator()` as you have here, the code works, but cannot be used to update the vector elements.  If you wish to update in place, you need to define instead as (for example):

```
 void operator() (int& i) { i *= 2; }
```

This is more typically how functors are defined - arguments are passed by reference rather than by value.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing a type or (quote) "name of a struct", but rather an object. The syntax

```
struct Foo {
} foo;
```

actually declares the type `Foo` and on object `foo` of type `Foo`.

Passing function objects instead of function pointers is prefered. See also
[this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.13) about why.

Answer (score 1):

The code is pretty well explained where, I think, you found it:

[The source of the code.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/)

The example on the site looks like this:

```
// for_each example
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void myfunction (int i) {
  cout << " " << i;
}

struct myclass {
  void operator() (int i) {cout << " " << i;}
} myobject;

int main () {
  vector<int> myvector;
  myvector.push_back(10);
  myvector.push_back(20);
  myvector.push_back(30);

  cout << "myvector contains:";
  for_each (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myfunction);

  // or:
  cout << "\nmyvector contains:";
  for_each (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myobject);

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are overloading `operator () (int)` for `myclass`, the function name is resolved from the struct itself. See [`for_each`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) for more info.