# Is it possible to figure out the parameter type and return type of a polymorphic C++ 14 lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, metaprogramming, c++14, template-meta-programming

Starting from this question ([Is it possible to figure out the parameter type and return type of a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda)) I used the proposed `function_traits` a lot. However, with C++14 polymorphic lambdas have arrived and they gave me a hard time.

```
template <typename T>
struct function_traits
    : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};
// For generic types, directly use the result of the signature of its 'operator()'

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
// we specialize for pointers to member function
{
    enum { arity = sizeof...(Args) };
    // arity is the number of arguments.

    typedef ReturnType result_type;

    template <size_t i>
    struct arg
    {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type type;
        // the i-th argument is equivalent to the i-th tuple element of a tuple
        // composed of those arguments.
    };
};
```

The `operator()` as proposed in the other question's answer is now overloaded as stated in the standard to support:

```
auto lambda1 = [](auto& a) { a.foo(); }
```

and

```
auto lambda2 = [](auto&&... args) { foo(args...); };
```

This overloading now rips the `function_traits` class apart because the compiler cannot resolve the correct version of `operator()`.

```
lambda.cpp:98:38: error: reference to overloaded function could not be
      resolved; did you mean to call it?
      typedef function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> caller;
```

Is it somehow possible to achieve the functionality of `function_traits` on polymorphic lambdas with C++14?

Comment: You have to provide parameter(s) type of `operator()` to be able to know its return type in case of overload as each overload may return a different type.

Comment: I would also guess that [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) should be able to get you that information. It may require an update vs the C++11 version, but it might just work anyways.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know the exact types of the lambda. I get the lambda and the arguments passed through a variadic template `template <typename L, typename...Ts> void foo(L lambda, Ts&&... args) { ... }` so i might now the lambda's argument types but not how it awaits them (as ref or val).

Comment: `decltype(lambda(std::forward<Ts>(args)...))` is the return type. Getting the parameter types requires another trait (that requires compiler magic) that's not in C++14. (It needs the invocation type traits in the library fundamentals 1 TS).

Comment: @T.C. is any compiler and STL implementation already supporting those traits?

Comment: None that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently impossible to do in the general sense, but if your lambdas have auto for all of their parameters and will work with all of them being replaced with some known type, you can modify the answer to this question:
[C++ metafunction to determine whether a type is callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100015/c-metafunction-to-determine-whether-a-type-is-callable)

Along the lines of

```
static const bool OneArg = (sizeof( test<T, int>(0)  ) == 1);
static const bool TwoArg = (sizeof( test<T, int, int>(0)  ) == 1);
static const bool ThreeArg = (sizeof( test<T, int, int, int>(0)  ) == 1);
static constexpr std::size_t TemplatedOperatorArgSize = 
    OneArg
        ? 1
        : TwoArg
            ? 2
            : ThreeArg
                ? 3
                : -1;
```

Apologies for the nested ternaries. And then use something like this to call it:

```
template<size_t N, typename T>
struct Apply {
    template<typename F, typename... A>
    static inline decltype(auto) apply(F && f, A &&... a) {
        return Apply<N-1, T>::apply(::std::forward<F>(f), std::declval<T>(), ::std::forward<A>(a)...);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Apply<0, T> {
    template<typename F, typename... A>
    static inline decltype(auto) apply(F && f, A &&... a) {
        return invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<A>(a)...);
    }
};

template<std::size_t Size, typename T, typename F>
inline decltype(auto) apply(F && f) {
    return Apply<Size, T>::apply(::std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

Using invoke from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke

Get the return type

```
using return_type = decltype(
    apply<has_callable_operator<T>::TemplatedOperatorArgSize, int>(function)
);
```

The first part could be rewritten to deal with an arbitrary number of arguments using `std::make_index_sequence`

But generally, I'd say you're going down a rabbit hole. Good luck.

Note: Didn't test the apply code, but it should be good enough to get you going.

Edit: Also, the return type needs to be independent of the parameter types to achieve what you want

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar case when implementing a ***Cache*** with a ***Fetch function***.
Something like:

```
template<class KEY, class VALUE, class FetchFunctor>
class Cache { ... };
```

---

### Phase 1

I wanted to save the user the need to state the type of his/her ***FetchFunctor*** and without the [C++17 class template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) I went for a ***createCahce*** helper method like this:

```
// [1]
template<class KEY, class VALUE, class FetchFunctor>
auto createCache(FetchFunctor fetchFunctor) {
    return Cache<KEY, VALUE, FetchFunctor>(fetchFunctor);
}
```

Thus creating the cache is quite easy, e.g.:

```
auto cache = createCache<int, int>([](int i){return i+3;});
```

---

### Phase 2

It would be much nicer to allow the user creating a cache without the need to provide the ***Key*** and ***Value*** types of the cache and to deduce them both from the provided ***FetchFunctor***. So I added an additional ***createCache*** method:

```
// [2]
template<class FetchFunctor>
auto createCache(FetchFunctor fetchFunctor) {
    // function_traits is a namespace where I 'hide' the
    // traits structs for result type and arguments type deduction
    using f = function_traits::traits<decltype(fetchFunctor)>;
    using KEY = typename f::template arg<0>::type;
    using VALUE = typename f::result_type;
    return Cache<KEY, VALUE, FetchFunctor>(fetchFunctor);
}
```

Now creating the cache is even easier:

```
auto cache = createCache([](int i){return i+3;});
```

---

### But, can both 'createCache' methods above live together?

Luckily yes.

1. If the user provides the template arguments **Key, Value** then the first one is the only match.
2. If the user doesn't provide the template arguments, the compiler considers the second one as **'more specialized'** and will prefer it.

This way we can support all the below cases:

```
    // [a]
    auto cache = createCache([](int i){return i+3;});
    // compiler deduces Key, Value to be: int, int - using the 2nd createCache

    // [b]
    auto cache = createCache<int, int>([](auto i){return i+3;});
    // we have a generic lambda so we provide Key and Value - using the 1st createCache

    // [c]
    auto cache = createCache<string, string>(
        [](const char* s){return string(s) + '!';}
    );
    // we want different Key and/or Value than would be deduced - we use 1st createCache
```

---

### Still...

The following will not compile:

```
    auto cache = createCache([](auto i){return i+3;});
    // we cannot deduce types for generic lambda
    // compiler goes to the 2nd createCache but Key and Value cannot be deduced
    // - compilation error
```

But this shouldn't bother us... you can provide Key and Value as in [b] above.

---

### Code:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e19151a5c245d7c3