# What is the correct way to check whether a template argument is a "true" callable object?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I have the following C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class T> void fun(T t) {
    if (t) std::cout << t();
    else std::cout << "no t";
}

int main() {
    std::function<int ()> f;
    fun(f); //The check will evaluate to false

    fun([](){return "hello";});

    int x = 2;
    fun([x](){return x;}); // Compiler error

    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't compile. The problem seems to be that a lambda that captures something is converted to a functor object, which in turn is not convertible to `bool` and therefore cannot be checked for truthfulness.

What's the right way of writing `fun` so that I can leave `main` as it is? Is there a way of doing this while keeping things simple (i.e. not specializing `fun`)?

**EDIT**: I really only care about checking whether `t` is true or not, and I am happy to assume that `T` is a callable type, without checking that explicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [C++ metafunction to determine whether a type is callable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100015/c-metafunction-to-determine-whether-a-type-is-callable)

Comment: You will find more searching the net: "c++ is_callable"

Comment: I read that other question and while it is similar, I don't think it's quite the same. That question is really about testing whether something is callable. In my case, I know that T is callable type, but I want to know whether an actual callable object was supplied or not. For example, in the code above, f is callable, but "empty". I'll edit the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to do some kind of specialization or overloading, but you can at least separate out the work into a predicate function:

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_constructible<bool, T>::value, bool>::type
okToCall(T&&t) { return static_cast<bool>(t); }
template<class T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<
  !std::is_constructible<bool, T>::value, bool>::type
okToCall(T&&) { return true; }

template<class T> void fun(T t) {
    if (okToCall(t)) std::cout << t();
    else std::cout << "no t";
}
```

Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a08468965ed6d54e

The only real difficulty is working out what to call the `okToCall` predicate function - what it's really doing is returning `true` if `T` is *not* convertible to `bool`, but its value converted to `bool` if it *is* convertible.

Comment: I suppose this answers the question OP asks in the body, but not in the title. The assumption is that any old pointer that can be converted to `true` is callable, which is false. `int b = 42;
    int* a = &b;
    fun(a);`

Comment: @AndyG You are right, but actually I only care about checking truthfulness, and am happy to assume that the type itself is callable. I edited the question to make this clear.

Comment: @ecatmur Thanks. This does answer my question, though I was hoping that there would be a smaller solution, or that something like `okToCall` would have been built-in in the standard library.

Comment: @Mitko yeah, sorry - the language isn't particularly good at this kind of thing currently. Some kind of static if facility (e.g. n4461, or http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2015/07/simulate-static_if-with-c11c14.html) would allow coding it without overloads.