# Member function call in decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, member-functions

The following code:

```
struct A
{
    int f(int);
    auto g(int x) -> decltype(f(x));
};
```

Fails to compile with the error:

```
error: cannot call member function 'int B::f(int)' without object
```

If I change it to:

```
struct A
{
    int f(int);
    auto g(int x) -> decltype(this->f(x));
};
```

I get another error:

```
error: invalid use of 'this' at top level
```

What is wrong with either of these? I am using gcc 4.6

Comment: Have you tried `decltype( declval<A>().f() )`? I think this is how c++0x `result_of` works. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689709/difference-between-stdresult-of-and-decltype/2689761#2689761

Comment: @Kitsune, neither `decltype(declval<A>().f())` nor `decltype(((A*)0)->f())` will work, it was tried. See my answer for something that does work, but it is ugly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently you can only access 'this' and members of the class **inside** the function body, but this is likely to be changed soon:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1207

Comment: @YSC - Right, it has moved to the list of fixed defects (and *was* added to the C++11 standard).

Answer (score 14):

Here are the magic words:

```
struct A
{
    int f(int);
    auto g(int x) -> decltype((((A*)0) ->* &A::f)(x)) ;
};
```

**Edit** I see from Mikael Persson's answer that this is how it's done in boost.

Answer (score 7):

result_of and decltype in combination can give the the return type for a member function

```
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int f(int i) { return i; } 
    auto g(int x) -> std::result_of<decltype(&A::f)(A, int)>::type
    { 
        return x;
    }
};


int main() {
    A a;
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a.f(123)), 
                  decltype(a.g(123))>::value, 
                  "should be identical");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I put up a [blog entry](http://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/c11-template-tricks-finding-the-return-value-type-for-member-function/)  where different use cases can be seen for when this is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

[Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) doesn't like `auto` as a top level return type, but the following compiles successfully:

```
template <typename R, typename C, typename A1> R get_return_type(R (C::*)(A1));

struct A
{
    int f(int);
    decltype(get_return_type(&A::f)) g(int x);
};
```

Basically, you have to declare at least one additional construct that gets you the type you want. And use `decltype` directly.

EDIT: Incidentally, this works fine for diving into the return type of a member function as well:

```
template <typename R, typename C, typename A1> R get_return_type(R (C::*)(A1));

struct B { int f(int); };

struct A
{
    int f(int);
    B h(int);

    decltype(get_return_type(&A::f)) g(int x);

    decltype(get_return_type(&A::h).f(0)) k(int x);
};

int main()
{
    return A().k(0);
}
```

Granted, it doesn't have the same convenience of `auto f()-> ...`, but at least it compiles.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work if f is a template member function unless you select the correct overload explicitly, which makes it even more verbose

Comment: @HighCommander4 Are you asking if there is a less ugly way to do this? I think the answer is no, for the very reasons you bring up.

Answer (score 3):

After some tests, neither `decltype(declval<A>().f(x))` nor `decltype(((A*)0)->f(x))` will work.

However, it seems that using boost::bind will work (and it's "under-the-hood" version):

```
struct A
{
    int f(int);
    auto g(int x) -> decltype(boost::bind(&A::f,0,x)());
    auto h(int x) -> decltype((((A*)0)->*(&A::f))(x)); //similarly (what Boost.Bind does under-the-hood.
};
```

Of course, this is not pretty. I guess you can look into how boost::bind does it to maybe find a nicer solution.

**EDIT**

As MSN suggested, you can also make your own function template to resolve this:

```
template< typename R, typename C, typename... Args > R member_func(R (C::*)(Args...)); 

struct A
{
    int f(int);
    auto g(int x) -> decltype(member_func(&A::f));
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I get: `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'A'`. Even if it worked, it would quite verbose, especially if there are multiple member function invocations in the return expression.

Comment: Good point, A is incomplete. Try with a pointer instead. See my edit.

Comment: The pointer version also gives `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'A'`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that does not work because the decltype is outside of the method and A is at that moment an incomplete type (so you can't even do `A().f(x)`).

But you should not really need that. Outside of the declaration of A this will work as expected, in A you should know the return type of the function that you declared a few lines above. Or you could just write:

```
struct A {
    typedef int ret_type;
    ret_type f(int x);
    ret_type g(int x);
};
```

This even works with plain c++03.

Comment: The example I gave is obviously simplified to highlight the problem. In my actual code, the return type of f is not "int", but some complicated expression involving Boost.Range transformations, bind-expressions, and so on (in fact, f itself uses decltype to declare its return type).

Comment: @HighCommander: So you manage to declare the return value once but not the second time?

Comment: @UncleBens: No, not even once. As I said, f itself uses decltype to declare its return type.

Comment: Did you try `typedef decltype(...) ret_type;`?

Comment: Yes, it has the same problem.

Comment: But in `(...)` you have to put whatever you put in `f` to declare the return type, not what you wrote in the question.