# How to deduce the type of the functor's return value?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I would like to write a template function which accepts 2 values and a functor or a lambda. 
The function calls the functor with those values and returns the result.

```
template <typename T, typename Fn> 
_ReturnTypeOfPred_ Apply(T x, T y, Fn fn)
  {
  return fn(x, y);
  }
```

Question: How can I define the return type of `Apply` to become equal to the return type of `Fn`? It is not necessarily equal to `T`, as in this example of the functor

```
template <typename T> 
auto Sum(T x, T y) -> decltype(x+y)
  {
  return x+y;
  }
```

**Update**

The 1st example was oversimplified.
Should this one work?

```
template <typename TContainer, typename Fn> 
auto Apply(const TContainer& x, const TContainer& y, Fn fn) -> decltype(fn(x.front(), y.front()))
  {
  return fn(x.front(), y.front());
  }
```

Would it always work if I repeat `return` expression in `decltype` of the return type? Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Underscore-capital names are reserved for the implementation. You mustn't use them in your own code.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It was a placeholder, not a real code

Comment: Good functors (such as those in the STL) always define their `return_type`, so you could just use `Fn::return_type`. But I understand you want an answer that also works for not-so-good functors.

Comment: @Gorpik: what if the functor is a lambda?

Comment: @Andrey: Ah, then you are toast, indeed. ecatmur's answer is the right thing here.

Comment: What does this get you that `bind`/`function` do not?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're nearly there; just use `decltype`:

```
template <typename T, typename Fn> 
auto Apply(T x, T y, Fn fn) -> decltype(fn(x, y))
{
  return fn(x, y);
}
```

You could use `std::result_of` ([Difference between std::result_of and decltype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689709/difference-between-stdresult-of-and-decltype)) but why bother?

```
template <typename T, typename Fn> 
typename std::result_of<Fn, T, T>::type Apply(T x, T y, Fn fn)
{
  return fn(x, y);
}
```

---

Regarding the follow-up question: for a function

```
auto fn(<args>) -> <return-type> { return <expression>; }
```

substituting `return-type` with `decltype(<expression>)` will *usually* work, but can be error prone.  For example, consider:

```
auto f(char c) -> decltype(std::string() += c) { return std::string() += c; }
```

Here `decltype` will yield `std::string &` and your function will return an lvalue reference to a local! This would have to be changed to:

```
auto f(char c) -> std::remove_reference<decltype(std::string() += c)>::type {
    return std::string() += c;
}
```

In other cases, `<expression>` could yield a value that is not returnable for reason of being e.g. noncopyable, containing a lambda, etc.

Comment: Thank you, could you please have a look at the updated question?

Comment: The question you linked doesn't underline the differences between `std::result_of` and `decltype` really well. For the purposes of the OP, `std::result_of` is not appropriate.