# How can I let the compiler deduce the return type of a template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm coming from Haskell and currently tinker with C++11 to see what it can do. One of my toys is a small template which attempts to imitate the Haskell `map` function, i.e. it takes a container of values of `X` and a function mapping an `X` to a `Y` and yields a container of values of `Y`. I know that I could easily do that using `std::transform`, but that would spoil the fun.

Right now, my template looks like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void myMap( const T &input,
            U &output,
            std::function<typename U::value_type (typename T::value_type)> f );
```

Now, my qustion is: is it possible to adjust the signature so that instead of taking the output container by reference (the second argument) I yield a new container via the return value and yet the compiler can deduce the return type? Something like

```
template <typename T, typename U>
U myMap( const T &input,
       std::function<typename U::value_type (typename T::value_type)> f );
```

unfortunately cannot be called like

```
std::vector<int> x = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::list<bool> y = myMap( x, []( int x ) { return x % 2 == 0; } );
```

...at least Clang fails to deduce the return type here.

One idea I had was that given that the input container type and the function type is known, you could construct the output type from that. I.e. something like

```
template <typename C, typename T, typename U>
C<U> myMap( const C<T> &input,
            std::function<U (T)> f );
```

...but alas `C<U>` doesn't even seem to be valid syntax. I wonder if I just need the right `decltype` fairy dust as was the case in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005749/how-to-deduce-the-type-of-the-functors-return-value?rq=1).

Comment: I remember doing something similar to what you want, except it didn't work very well with `std::string` because it was `std::basic_string<T, U>` and switching it caused it to be stuff like `std::basic_string<int, T>`. However I have an attempt that works on everything else.

Comment: Is `auto y = map<std::list>(x, [](int x){...});` acceptable? You can't deduce return type in C++.

Comment: In C++ we normally don't work with containers directly, we work with iterator ranges instead. Haskell and C++ don't translate well to each other. For each language, learn its ways.

Comment: @n.m.: Point taken. I know that this is not exactly idiomatic, I just happen to use this to stress the (meta-)type system of C++ a bit. :-)

Comment: `std::vector<int>::rebind<char>` would be interesting...  Allocators do it, why not containers?

Comment: If you're trying to implement Haskell concepts in C++, you'll have to think like a Haskell _compiler_ instead of a Haskell _writer_.  Instead of `myMap`, I'd write a transforming iterator, which would avoid the problem entirely.  [And boost already did it!](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html)

Comment: trailing return type isn't what u want?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yes, I know that I could implement a function very easily using iterators and ranges. This is just a (arguably absurd) problem I'm trying to solve to see what I can do with C++ templates.

Comment: @aaronman: If you believe that it would help, feel free to post an answer. :-)

Comment: @aaronman: no, I don't think that's what's needed here

Comment: @MooingDuck ahh, I see the issue, the 2 different templated containers  have unrelated types so it's "impossible" to find the return type of the container

Comment: It's not impossible to find the return type. It just takes some serious metawankery.

Comment: @ThePhD that's why i put it in quotes

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: After much experiementation, I don't think this is easily done.  Given a parameter that is a container, I don't think it's possible to deduce the unspecialized type of the container, making rebinding of any sort impossible.  I can make it work if you tell the function it's a vector though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for this syntax

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <list>

template 
    <
       template<typename, typename...> class Container, 
       typename InType, 
       typename FuncType, 
       typename... Rest
    >
auto myMap (const Container<InType, Rest...>& container,
            FuncType func) -> 
              Container<decltype(func(std::declval<InType>())), Rest...>
{
    Container<decltype(func(std::declval<InType>())), Rest...> result;
    std::transform(std::begin(container), 
                   std::end(container),
                   std::back_inserter(result), 
                   func);
    return result;
}
```

though I would not recommend using this style of code in any real project.

Comment: I like this one (it's a shorter version of the one I posted) but it doesn't work `std::array`.

Comment: `std::back_inserter` doesn't work with `std::array`, you need an overload for it anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that :)

Comment: I suggest using [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) to trim these `decltype(func(...))`.

Answer (score 8):

As I've stated before, I've done this before with everything but it fails to work with `std::basic_string<T,U>` (and `std::set` and friends due to the use of `std::back_inserter`) because it'll just rebind it to `std::basic_string<stuff,U>` rather than an underlying container. Do note however that it would be easy to extend it to work with a specialised case of `std::basic_string<T, U>`.

First thing I did was define a `function_traits` and a `Rebind` metafunction that would rebind types from `Container<T>` to `Container<U>` where `U` is the result type of the function being passed and `T` is the original type. The result type is found through the `function_traits` meta function. You can see the fully working code below:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>

/* Helpers */
template<typename T>
using Type = typename T::type;

template<typename T>
using Unqualified = Type<std::remove_reference<Type<std::remove_cv<T>>>>;

template<typename Specialization, typename Target>
struct rebind {};

/* Sensible default: assume first parameter is for the target */
template<template<typename...> class Cont, typename T, typename... Ts, typename Target>
struct rebind<Cont<T, Ts...>, Target> {
    using type = Cont<Target, Ts...>;
};

/* Special-case */
template<typename Old, std::size_t N, typename Target>
struct rebind<std::array<Old, N>, Target> {
    using type = std::array<Target, N>;
};

template<typename Specialization, typename Target>
using Rebind = Type<rebind<Specialization, Target>>;

#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
struct function_traits : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template<typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<R(T::*)(Args...) const> {

    static constexpr size_t args = sizeof...(Args);

    using result_type = R;
    template<size_t i>
    struct arg {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<i,std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
    };
};

template<typename T>
using Resultant = typename function_traits<T>::result_type;

template<class Cont, typename Map>
auto map(const Cont& cont, Map&& mapped) -> Rebind<Cont, Resultant<Unqualified<Map>>> {
    Rebind<Cont, Resultant<Unqualified<Map>>> result;
    auto result_iterator = std::back_inserter(result);
    for(const auto& elem : cont) {
        *result_iterator = mapped(elem);
    }
    return result;
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto i = map(std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6}, [](int x) { return x % 2 == 0; });
    for(auto&& j : i) {
        std::cout << j << ' ';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 0 1 0 1
```

**[Live version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=752df79f25f8c88d24dbcafa1283a208-93e6c6235a92d0c233f44beab03470ad) on Coliru**

Comment: Nice, it can't be any simpler than this though?

Comment: @aaronman I tried several approaches before but this one stuck out. I did want it to work with `std::string` and looking back at it I probably could if I tried a bit.

Comment: I guess this works, but the only situation in which I'd consider to do this would be a cocktail party with fellow programmers. It surely gets some golf-clapping. ;-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Ah, my code's changed a bit since then. After this answer I modulated everything into my own list comprehension library. Both the accepted answer and this one fail to work with allocator rebinding and `std::string`, both of which I ran into when taking my library thing seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new function declaration syntax in C++11.

```
template <typename T>
auto myMap(const T &input,
           std::function<typename U::value_type (typename T::value_type)> f ) -> decltype(...);
```

Where "..." is replaced by a single statement that the compiler then can evaluate a type from.  The difficult part is defining the return type in a single statement, though coming from Haskell you can likely figure it out.

With normal function declarations there isn't any way for the compiler to deduce return types from arguments, since the arguments haven't been parsed yet.  With this new syntax you can use the arguments to declare the return type.

The following is a case where you can have the compiler deduce the return type of a trivial function that isn't possible in C++98.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto add(T1 t1, T2 t2) -> decltype(t1+t2)
{ return t1 + t2; }
```

In C++14 they are adding some rules to allow the compiler to automagically deduce the return type without having to have the decltype construct.

Answer (score 0):

n.m.'s answer is what I would view as the *right* answer, but I don't think that the nested template's impact on usability is worth the correctness.

Here's my try at it:

```
template <typename T, typename F, typename C = 
        std::vector<typename std::result_of<F(typename T::value_type)>::type>>
C myMap(const T &input, F f) {
    C ret;
    for (const auto& x : input) {
        ret.push_back(f(x));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This illustrates two differences with your original code - one, I didn't specify std::function, as that class introduces overhead which is rarely necessary - the template will deduce the unutterable lambda type in your example just fine.  Two, I specified std::vector instead of std::list as the default return type (your example used list).  vector is the preferred C++ container - use it unless you have an overwhelmingly strong reason to use a different container backed by a benchmark.

One weakness of my aproach above is it can be difficult or impossible to list out the deduced types that are the previous arguments to the template.  The easiest way to solve this in my opinion is a hint argument:

```
template <class T> struct hint {};

template <typename T, typename F, typename C>
C myMap(const T& input, F f, hint<C> h) {
    return myMap<T, F, C>(input, f);
}
```

Of course, at this point you might as well take the output container as an input.