# Variadic template function accepting lambda

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

I'm trying to understand the compiler error that I'm getting fo the code below. I've got a variadic template function which accepts a lambda
with the specified types, and attempting to call that function results in the template not being considered a valid candidate due to a mismatch.

```
#include <functional>

template<typename ... ResultTypes>
void executeWithResultHandler(std::function<void (ResultTypes...)> lambda)
{
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    executeWithResultHandler<int>([] (int arg) {
    });
    return 0;
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 reduction.cpp 
reduction.cpp:10:5: error: no matching function for call to 'executeWithResultHandler'
    executeWithResultHandler<int>([] (int arg) {
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
reduction.cpp:4:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void (int, type-parameter-0-0...)>' against
      '<lambda at reduction.cpp:10:35>'
void executeWithResultHandler(std::function<void (ResultTypes...)> lambda)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

If I change the declaration to not be variadic:

```
template<typename ResultType>
void executeWithResultHandler(std::function<void (ResultType)> lambda)
{
}
```

then it works for the toy example above, but for the real problem I need arbitrary arguments.
Is there something I’m missing here, or anther way to accomplish this?

EDIT: This was marked as a duplicate incorrectly, I believe- the dupe does not answer the question I'm asking. This question specifically has to do with the **variadic template** issue here: Please note that, when I switch the template to be non-variadic the lambda converts to the std::function type correctly, as expected. This is true regardless of the number of arguments, as long as that is not handled in a variadic fashion.

However, it does **not** work with the variadic version specifically, despite an expectation that the parameter pack is unpacked to a set of real parameters, and the explicit specification of the template parameter list at the function call site.

Comment: lambda's are not `std::function` objects. They are just function objects with call `operator()`. So even if two lambda's have the same argument types and return type, they have two different types. See my related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628765/why-do-lambda-functions-in-c11-not-have-function-types

Comment: In a related question, I have a wrapper function http://stackoverflow.com/a/21000981/683218, which could make the std::function object accept lambda's for unambiguous cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with variadic templates in your case is that the compiler does not know whether the `int` you explicitly specified is the *complete* list for `ResultTypes...` or not, so it tries to deduce the optional remaining arguments from the parameter you gave it, and that obviously fails. This is a common pitfall with variadic template arguments and it is not limited to lambdas.

A solution always implies that you take away this option from the compiler, e.g.

```
template<typename ... ResultTypes>
void executeWithResultHandler_impl(std::function<void (ResultTypes...)> lambda)
{
}

template<typename ... ResultTypes, typename F>
void executeWithResultHandler(F&& lambda)
{
    executeWithResultHandler_impl(std::function<void (ResultTypes...)>(lambda));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628765/why-do-lambda-functions-in-c11-not-have-function-types) I'd previously linked as duplicate explains exactly what is going in your case.

An `std::function` is **not** a lambda, it is type of container that can store any kind of *callable* object. You can assign a lambda to an `std::function`, but in that case the necessary conversion is performed by the `std::function` constructor.

In your example

```
template<typename ... ResultTypes>
void executeWithResultHandler(std::function<void (ResultTypes...)> lambda)
{}

executeWithResultHandler<int>([](int arg){});
```

the compiler has no way of inferring the types in the parameter pack `ResultTypes` from the lambda expression above. Template argument deduction requires exact matches, implicit conversions are not considered, and the types involved here, as mentioned earlier, are completely different.

---

> If I change the declaration to not be variadic then it works

```
template<typename ResultType>
void executeWithResultHandler(std::function<void (ResultType)> lambda)
{}

 executeWithResultHandler<int>([](int arg){});
```

This works because there's no template argument deduction involved anymore. `executeWithResultHandler` takes exactly one template parameter, which you've explicitly specified, and because a lambda is implicitly convertible to `std::function`, overload resolution will find a match.

Note that in the first case there may have been more template arguments, in addition to `int`, that you hadn't specified explicitly.

---

You can get your original example to work by explicitly converting the lambda to `std::function`.

```
executeWithResultHandler<int>(std::function<void(int)>([] (int arg) {}));
```

Comment: Ah-ha. It's this bit that I was missing: "Note that in the first case there may have been more template arguments, in addition to int, that you hadn't specified explicitly." Thanks!