# What are unevaluated contexts in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

One example that frequently comes to mind is :

`sizeof` expression, where it doesn't evaluates the expression but determines the size by static type. For example :

```
int func();
sizeof(func());
```

This is my limit of thinking, so if there are other unevaluated contexts, then what are they?

Comment: I am really surprised that this question was not asked before (or I just didn't find it). It is a good one. Besides `sizeof`, I'm only aware of `decltype` and `noexcept`.

Comment: `auto` keyword when used for declaring and defining a variable?

Comment: @HappyCoder I think you confuse things.

Comment: Kindly explain? @bolov

Comment: @HappyCoder Maybe I misunderstood your point, but `auto x = 42` is not an unevaluated context as far as I know.

Comment: I meant `auto x=42ull;` or `auto str="me"s;` or the likes!

Comment: @HappyCoder: That has nothing to do with unevaluated contexts as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I would be very upset if I'd write `auto x = foo();` and the `foo()` were not evaluated.

Comment: Then I am wrong. Thanks for clearing it out guys :)

Comment: @5gon12eder I only meant the specific cases when the type is explicitly typed at the end.

Comment: @HappyCoder These are (in your example) an *integer suffix* and a *user-defined literal*. But I don't see what this has to do with unevaluated contexts or even `auto`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Fortunately, the standard has a handy list of those (§ 5 [expr] ¶ 8):

> In some contexts, *unevaluated operands* appear (5.2.8, 5.3.3, 5.3.7, 7.1.6.2). An unevaluated operand is not evaluated. An unevaluated operand is considered a full-expression.

Let's look at these in detail.

I will use the following declarations in my examples. The declared functions are never defined anywhere so if a call to them appears in an *evaluated* context, the program is ill-formed and we will get a link-time error. Calling them in an unevaluated context is fine, however.

```
int foo();  // never defined anywhere

struct widget
{
  virtual ~widget();
  static widget& get_instance();  // never defined anywhere
};
```

## `typeid`

§ 5.2.8 [expr.typeid] ¶ 3:

> When `typeid` is applied to **an expression other than a glvalue of a polymorphic class type**, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the static type of the expression. Lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) conversions are not applied to the expression. If the type of the expression is a class type, the class shall be completely-defined. **The expression is an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5).**

Note the emphasized exception for polymorphic classes (a `class` with at least one `virtual` member).

Therefore, this is okay

```
typeid( foo() )
```

and yields a `std::type_info` object for `int` while this

```
typeid( widget::get_instance() )
```

is not and will probably produce a link-time error. It has to evaluate the operand because the dynamic type is determined by looking up the `vptr` at run-time.

<rant>I find it quite confusing that the fact whether or not the static type of the operand is polymorphic changes the semantics of the operator in such dramatic, yet subtle, ways.</rant>

## `sizeof`

§ 5.3.3 [expr.sizeof] ¶ 1:

> The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. **The operand is either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5)**, or a parenthesized *type-id*. The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function or incomplete type, to an enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed before all its enumerators have been declared, to the parenthesized name of such types, or to a glvalue that designates a bit-field.

The following

```
sizeof( foo() )
```

is perfectly fine and equivalent to `sizeof(int)`.

```
sizeof( widget::get_instance() )
```

is allowed too. Note, however, that it is equivalent to `sizeof(widget)` and therefore probably not very useful on a polymorphic `return` type.

## `noexcept`

§ 5.3.7 [expr.unary.noexcept] ¶ 1:

> The `noexcept` operator determines whether the evaluation of **its operand, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5)**, can throw an exception (15.1).

The expression

```
noexcept( foo() )
```

is valid and evaluates to `false`.

Here is a more realistic example that is also valid.

```
void bar() noexcept(noexcept( widget::get_instance() ));
```

Note that only the inner `noexcept` is the operator while the outer is the specifier.

## `decltype`

§ 7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple] ¶ 4.4:

> **The operand of the `decltype` specifier is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5).**

The statement

```
decltype( foo() ) n = 42;
```

declares a variable `n` of type `int` and initializes it with the value 42.

```
auto baz() -> decltype( widget::get_instance() );
```

declares a function `baz` that takes no arguments and `return`s a `widget&`.

And that's all there are (as of C++14).

Comment: there was a point in the comments that `auto` is also involved. And the other answer also mentions `auto` but it is not clear. Is that the case?

Comment: `auto` is introduced in the same section as `decltype` but I don't see how it would be an unevaluated context. It doesn't even take an operand. And the only time the word “unevaluated” appears in § 7.1.6.2 is in the paragraph quoted in my answer. But IANAL.

Comment: @5gon12eder Why doesn't `typeid(*singleton::get_instance())` work?

Comment: @vsoftco Because `singleton` is polymorphic, the expression generates run-time code to follow the `vptr`. This means an actual call to the undefined function `singleton::get_instance`. See the first highlighted sentence in the standard quote. Personally, I find this tricky difference kind of awkward.

Comment: @5gon12eder Thanks, I missed *"other than a glvalue of a polymorphic class type"*.

Comment: Might be nice to fill in the other cases to say whether `*singleton::get_instance()` is allowed. The `foo()` cases are pretty obvious :-)

Comment: You can get even trickier with `auto` and `decltype()` if you use SFINAE. `template<class T> auto baz(T x) -> decltype(x.someFunc())` will cause that function to be chosen if `T::someFunc()` exists (while also providing the return type of `someFunc()`). This is primarily useful for a form of pseudo-specialization based on available member functions that wouldn't otherwise work due to how template substitution is evaluated (for example, when trying to provide a wrapper that will work with both `std::queue` and `std::stack`; `queue` uses `front` for the next-to-pop item while `stack` uses `top`)

Comment: Of course, you'll get an ambiguous overload error if you try to call the pseudo-specialized function with an object having both functions.

Comment: @JAB That's of course a more useful application than in my contrived examples but I wanted to keep the examples in the answer simple so people can understand them even if they don't know about more advanced features.

Comment: @5gon12eder I figured that people with enough knowledge of C++ to be interested in the term "unevaluated operand" would potentially be curious about more advanced uses of `auto`/`decltype()` as well. That's not even getting into `declval()`, which is _only_ usable in an unevaluated context. (There's also `std::result_of`, but the difference between that and `decltype` [is already covered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689709/difference-between-stdresult-of-and-decltype).)

Comment: As an aside, of those operators introducing an unevaluated context, only `sizeof` does not need parentheses around its argument (only needs it if applied to a type).

Comment: Regarding the interesting behavior of `typeid`: If there had been `decltype` already when it was introduced sometime in the forgotten past, I'm sure they would have simply made it a completely standard evaluated context in all circumstances.

Comment: @Deduplicator I was thinking about this too. But even in the past, they could have provided a `static_typeid` that never evaluates its operand and returns a `std::type_info` for the static type and a `dynamic_typeid` that always evaluates its operand and returns a `std::type_info` for the dynamic type which will always be the same for non-polymorphic types.

Comment: agree about the static vs. dynamic `typeid`. It is bad enough that `sizeof` also can be static vs. dynamic when variable length arrays are involved. This is a hindrance to generic programming, which is the most common scenario in which you actually use any of these operators.

Comment: But why can decltype work correctly on (widget::get_instance()) without calling the function while typeid can't?

Comment: C++20 has [updated this list](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.context) further so that it now contains `requires`, `concept`, and parts of a `template`'s preamble. It may be worth updating this answer to contain the new contexts for anyone who stumbles on this answer this in the future.

Answer (score 9):

The standard term is an *unevaluated operand* and you can find it in [expr]

> In some contexts, unevaluated operands appear (5.2.8, 5.3.3, 5.3.7, 7.1.6.2). An unevaluated operand is not evaluated. An unevaluated operand is considered a full-expression. [ Note: In an unevaluated operand, a non-static class member may be named (5.1) and naming of objects or functions does not, by itself, require that a definition be provided (3.2). —end note ]

- 5.2.8 covers `typeid`
- 5.3.3 covers `sizeof`
- 5.3.7 covers `noexcept`
- 7.1.6.2 covers simple type specifiers such as `auto` and `decltype` and POD types like `int`, `char`, `double` etc.