# What is a potentially-evaluated expression?

Tags: c++

I am reading about [ODR-use](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) and I encountered this:

> a variable x in a potentially-evaluated expression ex is odr-used
>   unless both of the following are true:

What is a *potentially-evaluated expression*?

Update: I might just found the answer when rolling down the page:

> In the definitions above, potentially-evaluated means the expression
>   is not an unevaluated operand (or its subexpression), such as the
>   operand of sizeof and a set of potential results of an expression e is
>   a (possibly empty) set of id-expressions that appear within e,
>   combined as follows:

But not sure if this is what it means in general + I do not really understand their explanation anyway. Also, why to say *potential result* instead of just *result*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In simplest terms, potentially-evaluated is exactly what it says it is: the expression has a chance to be evaluated. This includes anything except `sizeof(ex)`, `decltype(ex)`, `typeid(ex)` and `noexcept(ex)`. Other than in these contexts, *ex* is potentially-evaluated.

In relation to odr-used, it means *x* is considered odr-used only if *ex* is potentially-evaluated. That is to say, the necessary condition for *x* to be odr-used is that *ex* must be potentially-evaluated. This enables things such as

```
struct S
{
    static float f;  // declared but not defined
};

decltype(&S::f) p1;  // since &S::f isn't potentially evaluated, this is well-formed

float* p2 = &S::f;  // this is ill-formed
```

Comment: is "not potentially evaluated" equivalent with "unevaluated context"?

Comment: @bolov [I would guess so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088599/what-are-unevaluated-contexts-in-c). To be sure, I don't know where "unevaluated context" appears so I'm not 100% sure. It doesn't appear in either [[expr](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#def:unevaluated_operand)] nor [[basic.def.odr](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr)]

Comment: @PasserBy Search for unevaluated operands.

Comment: "It means x is considered odr-used only if ex is potentially-evaluated" but what does "potentially-evaluated" mean?

Comment: @NeiLee I'm bad at explaining this, hopefully the reworded version is better

Comment: Well it helped but I still do not get why expression can be considered only potentially evaluated and not just evaluated or not evaluated?

Comment: @NeiLee Because a potentially-evaluated expression might not end up being evaluated too, for instance if you have a tautology in a branch, the contents of the branch is still considered potentially-evaluated.

Comment: Ah I think I get it, but what would make an expression that usually would be evaluated to not get evaluated? Since they only are potentially-evaluated, like "float* p2 = &S::f;", would this not always be evaluated or what?

Comment: @NeiLee Yes `float* p2 = &S::f` is always evaluated, but that doesn't conflict with the fact it is potentially-evaluated?

Comment: Okay then this is exactly what still confuses me a little; If this expression always is evaluated, why say that it is **potentially**-evaluated?

Comment: @NeiLee A certainly evaluated expression is just a subset of potentially-evaluated expressions? Since we only wanted the properties of a potentially-evaluated expression, we don't bother with saying it is certainly evaluated.

Comment: @user8221510 A potentially evaluated expression is not necessarily evaluated as can be seen in [\[basic.def.odr\]/(2.6)](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#2.6) and [\[expr.cond\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#1).

Comment: For "potentially" part: IIUC `ex2` is potentially-evaluated in `true ? ex1 : ex2`, even it is never evaluated.