# The problem of libstdc++‘s implementation of std::declval

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++20, type-traits

Unlike [libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/type_traits#L1369) or [MSVC-STL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/type_traits#L147) that only declares the function signature of `std::declval`, [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/type_traits#L2379) defines the function body for `std::declval`, and uses `static_assert` internally to ensure that it must be used in unevaluated contexts:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Up = _Tp&&>
_Up 
__declval(int);

template<typename _Tp>
_Tp 
__declval(long);

template<typename _Tp>
auto 
declval() noexcept -> decltype(__declval<_Tp>(0));

template<typename _Tp>
struct __declval_protector {
  static const bool __stop = false;
};

template<typename _Tp>
auto 
declval() noexcept -> decltype(__declval<_Tp>(0)) {
  static_assert(__declval_protector<_Tp>::__stop,
    "declval() must not be used!");
  return __declval<_Tp>(0);
}
```

When we try to evaluate the return value of `std::declval`, this `static_assert` will be triggered:

```
auto x = std::declval<int>(); // static assertion failed: declval() must not be used!
```

But I found that in this implementation, the following code will also be rejected because `static_assert` fails ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xenzr79q4)):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
auto type() { return std::declval<T>(); }

using T = decltype(type<int>());
```

But it seems that `std::declval` is still used in an unevaluated context since we have not actually evaluated it.

Is the above code well-formed? If so, is it a library implementation bug? How does the standard specify this?

Comment: the last godbolt link is to the wrong example

Comment: `std::declval` is only allowed in unevaluated expressions.  `return std::declval<T>();` is not an unevaluated expression.  I think clang is right to reject this code.

Comment: see here for what an unevaluated context is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088599/what-are-unevaluated-contexts-in-c. A function that you don't call is not an unevaluated context

Comment: Note that libstdc++'s implementation of `std::declval` would make the program ill-formed, no diagnostic required outside of the implementation of the std library.  But the same might be true of the other ones (the requirement that all specializations must have a legal instantiation; `__declval_protector` attempts to work around that, but being sneaky doesn't make it well formed).  This is not actually a problem, because the standard places no restrictions on the contents of std header files.

Comment: The issue is fixed for MSVC: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/f75c7f596c7b491168fefb5eff5164ab7ae36867/stl/inc/type_traits#L135-L137 . The fix will be available in VS 2022

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The example is ill-formed, because the restriction for `std::declval` is actually on the expression where `declval` is named, not on whether the abstract virtual machine would actually evaluate its call.

The requirement on `std::declval` is [[declval].2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/declval#2)

> *Mandates:* This function is not odr-used ([basic.def.odr]).

where "Mandates" means ([[structure.specifications]/(3.2)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/structure.specifications#3.2))

> *Mandates:* the conditions that, if not met, render the program ill-formed.

In [[basic.def.odr]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.def.odr#7):

> A function is odr-used if it is named by a potentially-evaluated expression or conversion.

And in [[basic.def.odr]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.def.odr#2):

> An expression or conversion is *potentially evaluated* unless it is an unevaluated operand ([expr.prop]), a subexpression thereof, or a conversion in an initialization or conversion sequence in such a context.

Note the expression `type<int>()` in the last line is an unevaluated operand. But the distinct expression `std::declval<T>()` in the instantiated definition of `type` is potentially evaluated. It doesn't matter that ignoring that, it would not actually be evaluated.

So actually the libc++ and MSVC-STL implementations are incorrect, because an ill-formed program should be diagnosed unless otherwise noted.