# Can I write a function type that returns a function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, result-of

The following fails to compile on both gcc and clang

```
#include <type_traits>

int foo();

int main()
{
    using R = std::result_of_t<decltype(foo)()>; // error
}
```

The error on both compilers deals with the illegality of declaring a function returning a function. But I'm not declaring such a function - I'm just trying to write its type - since that's what `result_of` expects. Is this really still ill-formed?

Comment: I think that this "The error on both compilers deals with the illegality of declaring a function returning a function." would be usefully replaced by the actual error

Comment: Why don't you just use `decltype(foo())`?

Comment: You're not allowed to form a function type where the function returns another function type. "Functions shall not have a return type of
type array or function" dcl.fct/8

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas `std::result_of_t<T>` is `typename std::result_of<T>::type`.

Comment: Whoops: read it as C++11.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919375/why-isnt-stdresult-ofintinttype-valid

Comment: It looks like this is related to the fact that `int` is not a complete type and cannot grab the `type` from `typename result_of<int>::type`.

Comment: Changing the statement to `using R = std::result_of_t<decltype(foo)&()>;` works as desired.

Comment: @callyalater Clearly, because now we're returning a reference to a function. This question is about creating *type-id*s that would correspond to ill-formed declarations.

Comment: @Caramiriel Not really, that question involves misusing `result_of`.

Comment: @Guiroux Not really - they both just say it's illegal to declare a function returning a function, in different words.

Comment: @StenSoft Because the question is about why I can't do it this way.

Comment: This is called out as one of the cases causing deduction failures in a SFINAE context; see the long note in http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#8, last two bullet points.

Comment: Was that code generated by macro originally?  `decltype((foo))()` should solve it if so.   However this may change semantics (to arguably more correct ones, as yours calls the theoretical rvalue `()` on a more general `foo`).

Comment: @Yakk Naw, origin was [T.C.'s comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834026/on-the-various-ways-of-getting-the-result-type-of-a-function?lq=1#comment59341194_35834144) on a different question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're passing a *type-id*, which is defined in [[dcl.name]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.name) as

> […] syntactically a declaration for a variable or function of that type that omits the name of the entity. […] It is possible to identify uniquely the location in the *abstract-declarator* where the identifier would appear **if the construction were a declarator in a declaration. The named type is then the same as the type of the
>   hypothetical identifier.**

For the hypothetical identifier to have some type, the hypothetical declaration must be well-formed in the first place. But it isn't as per [[dcl.fct]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#10). Hence the program is ill-formed (and the compilers'  error messages are actually comprehensible). This case is also more directly covered by [[temp.deduct]/(8.10)](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#8), implying that this is a (SFINAE-friendly) error.

---

In fact, merely implying an invalid type's usage suffices to make the program ill-formed. E.g. creating the type pointer to function returning function is ill-formed:

```
using f = int();
using t = f(*)();
```

So is the following:

```
struct A {virtual void f() = 0;};
using t = A(*)();
```

(Clang shouldn't be accepting this. C.f. GCC bug [17232](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17232)'s interesting discussion).