# C++14 'auto' is able to get function return type, do we still need std::result_of<>?

Tags: c++, types, return, c++14, auto

Seems C++14 `auto` keyword can be used to appear at the location of function definition as to indicate the return type. In this case, is `std::result_of` still needed? Isn't it obsolete now?

Comment: It might be more convenient to use `std::result_of` instead of an `auto` declaration, then taking a `decltype` of that. Having more choices and options, at one's disposal, is always a good thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

1. Sometimes you want the return type, but not as the result of the function. Let's say I have a `vector<X>` and I want to apply a function to each element and return the result. This operation is called `map` or `fmap`, and we might implement the signature thusly:

   ```
   template <class T, class F,
       class U = std::decay_t<std::result_of_t<F&(T const&)>>>
   std::vector<U> map(std::vector<T> const&, F );
   ```

   You could make the return type `auto`, but regardless, you need to compute that type `U` and `auto` won't give it to you. Any time you want the result of a function call that won't necessarily be the return type, `auto` won't cut it.
2. SFINAE. Consider the difference between:

   ```
   template <class F>
   decltype(auto) foo(F f) { return f(0); }
   template <class F>
   std::result_of_t<F&(int)> bar(F f) { return f(0); }
   ```

   If `F` is not invokable with an `int`, then instantiating `foo()` is a hard compile error but `bar()` would simply be removed from the overload set. This can be very valuable in generic code, as you can test expressions for well-formedness.
3. Annotation. `auto` tells you nothing about the function return type. If the function is returning the result of invoking one callable with some args, `std::result_of_t<F(A, B)>` in of itself tells me what that function is doing. `auto` tells me nothing.

---

Really a better question may be... why do we need `std::result_of` if we have `decltype`. Those seem more closely related. After all, I can do `decltype(x+1)`, how would I express that in terms of `result_of`?! `decltype` is clearly better. Well, it turns out there are [some slight differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35834192/2069064) between the two even when it comes to determining the result of a function invocation.